# How run a native android Activity using titanium module?

Tags: android, android-activity, module, titanium, appcelerator

I need to call a custom activity that is written in android in titanium studio. 
How should I run this code in accelerator?

The module code is this :

```
ChoosePDFActivity cpa = new ChoosePDFActivity();

Intent intent = new Intent(); 
intent.setClassName("com.pdfreader.my", "com.artifex.mupdf.MuPDFActivity");
Activity activity = TiApplication.getAppRootOrCurrentActivity();

activity.startActivity(cpa.showPDF());
```

Tiapp setting is :

```
<modules>
   <module platform="android">com.pdfreader.my</module>      
</modules>
```

and titanium code is :

```
var sample_module = require('com.pdfreader.my');
sample_module.example()
```

Nothing happen whenever i run my code? if i return a string i can show it in my titanium but i cannot run activity, can anyone help me?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem by changing my Java code:

```
final File file = new File(path);       

Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName("com.artifex.mupdf", "com.artifex.mupdf.MuPDFActivity");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(uri);
Activity activity = TiApplication.getAppRootOrCurrentActivity();
activity.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

`require()` is used to include CommonJS modules inside, it doesn't create Intent.

If you want to create Intent inside your titanium application follow [documentation about Android platform](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Android_Platform_Overview-section-29004888_AndroidPlatformOverview-ApplicationComponents)